# awk sub ++count every 4 matches unlike every 1 match

Tags: unix, awk, text-processing

Let's say I have the following `1.txt` file below:

```
    one file.txt
    two file.txt
    three file.txt
    
    four file.txt
    five file.txt
    sixt file.txt

    seven file.txt
    eight file.txt
    nine file.txt
```

I usually use the following command below to sequentially rename the files listed at `1.txt`:

```
awk '/\.txt/{sub(".txt",++count"&")} 1' 1.txt > 2.txt
```

The output is `2.txt`:

```
one file1.txt
two file2.txt
three file3.txt

four file4.txt
five file5.txt
sixt file6.txt

seven file7.txt
eight file8.txt
nine file9.txt
```

But I would like to rename only every 4 matches when the pattern is `.txt`.

to clarify, a pseudocode would be something like:

```
awk '/\.txt/{sub(".txt",++count"&")} 1 | <change every 4 matches> ' 1.txt > 3.txt
```

such that `3.txt` is as below:

```
one file.txt
two file.txt
three file.txt

four file1.txt <-here
five file.txt
sixt file.txt

seven file.txt
eight file2.txt <- here
nine file.txt
```

I have been looking for both the web and in my learning and I do not remember something like that and I am having difficulty starting something to achieve this result.

**Note:** Maybe I just need to continue the command below:

```
awk -v n=0 '/\.txt/{if (n++==4) sub(".txt",++count"&")} 1'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. Would you please try:

```
awk '/\.txt/ {if (++n%4==0) sub(".txt",++count"&")} 1' 1.txt > 2.txt
```

The condition `++n%4==0` meets every four valid lines.

Answer (score 4):

Adding 1 more `awk` variant here, based on your shown samples only. Simple explanation would be, check if line is NOT NULL AND count variable value is 4, then substitute .txt with count1(increasing with 1 each time) with .txt itself and print the line.

```
awk 'NF && ++count==4{sub(/\.txt/,++count1"&");count=0} 1' 1.txt > 2.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be passing `n=4` to use it for both the modulo and the division.

For the string you could pass `s=".txt"` for [index()](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) to check if it present and for sub to use in the replacement.

```
awk -v str=".txt" -v nr=4 'index($0,str){if(!(++i%nr)) sub(str,i/nr"&")}1' 1.txt > 2.txt
```