# Repeat nth number until the nth match while prefixing these number at the pattern using awk sub

Tags: awk, gsub, text-processing

I have the following file below containing `15` times string `.dog`.
Usually when I want to append any numeral for counting at string, I use `awk '/\.dog/{sub(".dog",++count"&")} 1'` and also use some variations of this command a few times as in this question [awk sub ++count every 4 matches unlike every 1 match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69429958/awk-sub-count-every-4-matches-unlike-every-1-match).

```
 [.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[.dog]
```

At the moment I had to do different such that a unique *nth numeral* is appended up to the *nth match*, that is, that each *nth numeral* (1, 2, 3, etc.) is repeated until the *nth matc*h. Let's say I want it `.dog` be my pattern, and that up to *5 nth* match of `.dog` the `awk.. gsub.. count` command repeat *1* while appending up a numeral. So my output should be:

```
[1.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[1.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[1.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[1.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[1.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[2.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[2.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[2.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[2.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[2.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[3.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[3.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[3.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[3.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[3.dog]
```

I have been looking for a solution but I do not have found, I believe that again can find this solution manipulating and adapting `awk '/\.dog/{sub(".dog",++count"&")} 1 | <at the every 5 matches> '` but I'm still not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '$0=="[.dog]"{ if (++cnt % 5 == 1) idx++; sub(/\./,idx".") } 1' file
[1.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[1.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[1.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[1.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[1.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[2.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[2.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[2.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[2.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[2.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[3.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[3.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[3.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[3.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[3.dog]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this `awk`

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="["} {split($2,a,".")}/dog/{a[1]=int(dog++/5);$2=a[1]+1"."a[2]}1' input_file
```

By splitting every match of `dog` into 20% or 0.2, this will generate 5 matches within an integer, `int` suppresses the float decimals so there may be a better approach for this.

**Output**

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="["} {split($2,a,".")}/dog/{a[1]=int(dog++/5);$2=a[1]+1"."a[2]}1' input_file
[1.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[1.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[1.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[1.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[1.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[2.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[2.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[2.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[2.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[2.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[3.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[3.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[3.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[3.dog]
-house
[.cat]
-kitchen
[3.dog]
```

Comment: by @Cyrus comment: `awk 'BEGIN{ count=1 } /\.dog/{ t=count; sub(/\..*/,"",t); sub(".dog", t "&"); count+=.2 }1' file` worked also!

Answer (score 1):

A answer by user @Cyrus:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ count=1 } /\.dog/{ t=count; sub(/\..*/,"",t); sub(".dog", t "&"); count+=.2 }1' file
```

Comment: That's doing a few unnecessary things and so could be reduced to `awk '/\.dog/{ sub(".dog", int(count+1) "&"); count+=.2 }1' file` but it's hard-coding `.2` which isn't always a nice simple number for repetitions other than 5 (e.g. try it for repetitions of 3), may run into floating point arithmetic rounding issues, doing a regexp comparison when a string comparison is called for, prone to matching the wrong strings, and leaving the RE metachar unescaped in the sub() so YMMV depending on your real file contents.

Comment: @EdMorton Yes, I am considering editing my post, there are contexts where none of the answers work without changing other parts, I really posted a MWE and this did not take into account other things, it really was the fault of me not to specify the context, but I would like request these context compensations, I will edit my post and then you can understand what happened

Comment: Don't do that. Accept an answer to the question you asked, and ask a new followup question if you can't make the solution work on your real data with a [mcve] that better represents your real data. [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged.

Comment: @EdMorton At least Cyrus response has been better to adapt to avoid unwanted effects, and this adaptation can not do in your response.

Comment: @EdMorton I will plan a new question with the context adaptations I need.

Comment: All we can do is answer the question you asked. It's always trivial to match the text you want to match and much harder to not also match text you did not want to match. I would expect this answer to "adapt" because it matches more than you asked for so it'll "adapt" to other things as well - thats a bug, not a feature. Try replacing `.cat` with `.dogfish` in your sample input then running both solutions. Just because you don't see how to modify my answer to your real data doesn't mean it's not the better answer to the question you asked and/or the better approach to processing your real data.

Comment: @EdMorton Changing `.dog` to `.dogfish` really works but not in this case, see here a sample of your code https://onlinegdb.com/ZWISqGBRj

Comment: That is definitely NOT my code, it's trying to use regexp metachars in a literal string comparison, is using those chars as if they were globbing chars instead of regexp chars, and isn't bounding the text you want to match. If you have a new question then please just post it as such on the site with it's own [mcve] so we can help you. We can't help you robustly parse text if we don't know what the text you're trying to parse looks like.

Comment: I didn't suggest changing `.dog` to `.dogfish`, I suggested changing `.cat` to `.dogfish` so you can see that my answer continues to update the `.dog` lines correctly while the scripts in the other answers posted will fail as they'll also update the `.dogfish` lines. That's one manifestation of the problem I'm telling you about - it's always easy to match the lines you want but much harder to not match similar lines you don't want.

Comment: So far we know that the answer I posted does exactly what you want for the format of input you posted and that you have data in a different format from that shown in your question that you'd like a similar solution for but without a new question showing that new input/output that includes cases my answer doesn't work for, we'd just be guessing at how to help you and the result would almost certainly be fragile (like the other answers here) and fail later in the field with real data.

Comment: @EdMorton yes I'm making a new question, but a little time and post it.

Comment: @EdMorton see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69788918/repeat-nth-number-until-the-nth-match-while-appending-in-different-contexts-us